# Can't access variables using getter

Tags: java, setter, getter

So hey guys, im having some trouble with a script i am writing (with a custom api and stuff)
So what i have is a main class where i use data from my GUI to edit variables in my ScriptVariables class like this:

```
GUI g = new GUI();     
ScriptVariables sv = new ScriptVariables();   
String foodNameString = g.textField.getText();
sv.setFoodName(foodNameString);

String amountString = g.textField_1.getText();
int amountInt = Integer.parseInt(amountString);
sv.setAmount(amountInt);

double healthPercentageValue = g.slider.getValue();
sv.setHealthPercentage(healthPercentageValue);
```

(Ps: i logged this with getter and this bit works fine)
Now in another class i try to access it AFTER that previous code is executed i do it like this:

```
ScriptVariables sv = new ScriptVariables();

String foodName2 = sv.getFoodName();
int amount2 = sv.getAmount();
```

Now the problem is when i log those vars i get null for the string and 0 for the int.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing two different instances of `ScriptVariables` so they don't share instance variables. The fact that you have set the `text` and `foodName` properties on the first instance does not affect the new instance you create in your other class.

What you can do is either make the `text` and `foodName` properties `static`, or pass a reference to the first `ScriptVariables` instance to the second piece of code.

Comment: Ok how do i pass the reference of the first instance to the second one?

Comment: A common way is to pass it via the constructor when you instantiate the second class.

Answer (score 1):

`ScriptVariables sv = new ScriptVariables();` is creating a different instance than the one for which you previously set its fields (`foodName` and `amount`). This new instance has its `foodName` and `amount` fields still not initialized, hence the null and zero values.

Assuming your second class is `ScriptVariablesAccessor`, then you can include a field of type `ScriptVariables` in its class definition. This field would then be used to pass the previously filled instance via a constructor or a setter method.

```
public class ScriptVariablesAccessor {
   private ScriptVariables sv;

   public ScriptVariablesAccessor(ScriptVariables sv) {
      this.sv = sv;
   }

   // or use a setter
   public void setScriptVariables(ScriptVariables sv) {
      this.sv = sv;
   }

   public void processVariables() {
      String foodName = sv.getFoodName();
      int amount = sv.getAmount();
      // do something with foodName and amount;
   }
}
```

Below is how you would call this class with the prepared `ScriptVariables`:

```
ScriptVariablesAccessor svAccessor = new ScriptVariablesAccessor(sv);
svAccessor.processVariables();
```

Answer (score 0):

You created two different `ScriptVariables` objects.

`foodNameString` and `amountString` can be created in `static`, and since you are getting them from another class, you can set them to `public` or `protected` but not `private` , then call `ClassName.amountString` to get the value.

Or you can apply the `Singleton` Pattern.

Or just simply pass the `ScriptVariables` object or those strings to another class's method.